# Kubernetes + kustomize: How to use 'var' in configMapGenerator?

Tags: kubernetes

In my `kustomization.yaml` I have:

```yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: nginx-config
    files:
      - nginx.conf
vars:
  - name: PHP_FPM
    objref:
      kind: Service
      name: app-service
      apiVersion: v1
    fieldref:
      fieldpath: metadata.name
```

And then in `nginx.conf` I have:

```
    location = /index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass $(PHP_FPM):9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /app/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
```

When I run `kustomize` the var isn't replaced:

```sh
❯ kustomize build kubernetes/overlays/staging | grep fastcgi_pass
2020/06/07 18:25:05 well-defined vars that were never replaced: PHP_FPM
            fastcgi_pass $(PHP_FPM):9000;
```

How can I get my service name into `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Kustomize can be customized to allow vars in `ConfigMap.data`. It's not well-documented, but you can find it buried in some Github issue which I don't feel  like digging up right now.

Comment: See varReference configurations: https://github.com/innoq/advanced-kustomize-examples/tree/main/var-reference-configuration-example

Answer (score 2):

According to the fact that Nginx [doesn't support variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432888) in the config file, the file should be adjusted before it's applied to the Nginx container.

`Kustomize` **vars** allowed only in [particular places](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2052) and `ConfigMap.data` is not one of them at this moment.

The error tells you that `PHP_FPM` variable is defined in `kustomization.yaml` but never used for replacement. <sup>[Link1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/7b7126358388be17949efafcb6811bbbc88a263b/api/internal/accumulator/resaccumulator_test.go#L129)   [Link2](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/6bb470dbd091c0aeacc2b29ae9ff5cafe73b3abe/api/internal/accumulator/resaccumulator.go#L154)</sup>

Nevertheless, the problem could be solved by adjusting `nginx.conf` content using the `Init Container` and then mount it to the `Main container`.

#### Example:

**kustomization.yaml:**

```
resources:
- cm-init-pod.yaml
- svc.yaml

patches:
- patch.yaml

configMapGenerator:
  - name: mymap
    files:
      - nginx.conf
vars:
  - name: PHP_FPM
    objref:
      kind: Service
      name: app-service
      apiVersion: v1
    fieldref:
      fieldpath: metadata.name
```

**cm-init-pod.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cm-vol-pod 
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx 
      image: nginx
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
blalb-a
bla-bla
backend ##PHP_FPM##
bl-abla
bla-bla
```

**svc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

**patch.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cm-vol-pod 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx 
      image: nginx
      command: [ "bash", "-c", "nginx -g \"daemon off;\""  ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: ed
# this is not a real nginx.conf so I've put it next to the original one
        mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf1 
        subPath: nginx.conf
  initContainers:
    - name: init
      image: nginx
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cp /mnt/cm/nginx.conf /mnt/ed/nginx.conf && sed -i 's/##PHP_FPM##/$(PHP_FPM)/' /mnt/ed/nginx.conf" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: cm
        mountPath: /mnt/cm
      - name: ed
        mountPath: /mnt/ed
  volumes:
    - name: cm
      configMap:
        name: mymap
    - name: ed
      emptyDir: {}
```

#### Results:

```
$ kustomize build | kubectl apply -f -
# or kubectl apply -k ./

configmap/mymap-k2hbfmf776 created
service/app-service created
pod/cm-vol-pod created

$ kubectl exec -it cm-vol-pod -- bash

root@cm-vol-pod:/# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf1

blalb-a
bla-bla
backend app-service
bl-abla
bla-bla
```

#### Let's clean up everything

```
$ kustomize build | kubectl delete -f -

# or

$ kubectl delete -k ./

configmap "mymap-k2hbfmf776" deleted
service "app-service" deleted
pod "cm-vol-pod" deleted
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty heavy solution to replace one var, but I guess it works :-)

Comment: I just wanted to keep everything important that you mentioned to ensure that it fits the proposed flow. Eventually, You can end-up with just one well-tailored InitContainer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375369/openshift-or-kubernate-environment-variables-from-file